# Retriving index value of an array in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am having a 2D array.

```
grid[0][0]= hat
grid[0][1]= cat
grid[1][1]= bat
```

Now, if I have the value `cat`, could I retrieve those index i.e `[0][1]`

Comment: Are you looking for something to search for a specific value's position in the array?

Comment: @Jenny  If you like my answer, you should accept this. Just `click` left side and accept. you will also get some point

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over all the elements like this:

```
def find(needle, hay):
  for x in hay:
    for y in x:
      if hay[x][y] == needle: return x, y
  return -1, -1
```

And then use this function

```
find('cat', grid)
```

Comment: I am declaring my multidimensional array this way                                  grid=[[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]                                                                     On calling find() it is throwing this error:                                                   TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can do by

```
for i in grid:
    for j in i:
        if grid[i][j] == 'cat':
            print i, j
```

Output:

```
0 1
```